# After enable SSL Certificate still has SSL connect error for woocommerce checkout

Tags: wordpress, ssl, paypal, woocommerce, paypal-sandbox

In my site I have `SSL certificate`  enabled and also  `Force secure checkout` enabled. 
I'm using  `TLS 1.2` .

also using [WordPress HTTPS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/) for https. but when I'm checkout through paypal sandbox its showing `SSL connect error` .

How to solve this problem?

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you're running into is the POODLE vulnerability issue.  You don't need an SSL installed on the site.  You just need to make sure your server's software stack is up to date.

Take a look at [this info](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-ssl-error-poodle-vunerability//) for more details.